# Anyway to wire a button without an updatepanel?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, updatepanel

When dealing with update panels I normally am dealing with a single control and handle everything else through JavaScript.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel1" childrenastriggers="false" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:button id="button1" runat="server" onclick="update()" />
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This seems like too much code for a simple postback. If I remember right there's a way to just wire up the button to do the postback without requiring an updatepanel. I still want access to scriptmanager to call a JS function once the update is complete. Any ideas on a cleaner solution?

Comment: I'm not getting what you want to do, try to explain better your quiestion

Comment: Try this answer I gave to another question: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669904/what-are-some-simple-and-fast-ways-to-retieve-session-variables-using-javascript/20671311#20671311

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do here.. You don't need a updatepanel to trigger a button click event .. Just the button is enough.. 
Do you want to handle server side or client side code on the click of the button.. Also you are not closing the button tag properly.. It should be like this

OnClick is the server side event and OnClientClick is the client click event

```
// This is the server side code that has to be written
    void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void Btn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid doing a full post back. That way causes the page to reload every time you click the button. And yea, I know about the button. Was just typing that up as an example. I'll fix it.

Comment: Why don't you write up Client side or jQuery code to do the task without a postback

Comment: It requires a database update. A basic example may be a "like" button where the information is stored in the database.

Comment: Then you can send an ajax request.. There won't be any postback then