# simple and fast ways to retrieve session variables using Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, session

I am a bit of a novice on web UI development using jQuery and/or Javascript.  I have to use it as part of my project, but I am NOT an expert.

I would really, really appreciate insight from someone who knows this area better than I.

#### MY REQUIREMENT

I have a button on a page inside of an update panel.

**I need to set a value in a variable in the code behind** of an ASP.Net web application when the button is clicked programmatically from a jQuery/Javascript function.

**I then need to pass this changed variable back to the page** from the code behind.  The value of this variable will determine how another jQuery/Javascript function behaves on further user action.

**I cannot use hidden fields** as they are getting reset inside the update panel by my `OnUnload` method for the panel.

#### MY QUESTION

**Is there a simple and fast way for a jQuery/Javascript function** OUTSIDE of this update panel to **retrieve the variable from the session** if I populate it in the code behind upon the button click inside the update panel?  Is this possible?

**MY UI CODE**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" OnUnload="UpdatePanel_Unload">
<ContentTemplate>

 <asp:Button ID="btnSendMeTheField" runat="server" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"  OnClick="btnSendMeTheField_Click"/>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**THE SERVER CODE THAT PROCESSES THE DATA AND SENDS BACK THE VARIABLE**

```
Protected Sub btnSendMeTheField_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSendMeTheField.Click
                Dim parsedObjectId As String = ""
                parsedObjectId = "1000"
                Session("objectId") = parsedObjectId
End Sub
```

Comment: There's only one way to do it. Ajax request. Keep in mind, the update panel uses an ajax request, so you can likely send that data back through the update panel as an html attribute then access it with jquery.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Kevin.  I will look that up right away. Do you know of any good examples?

Comment: Not really, i personally wouldn't use an ajax request since it would be one more request that is likely not needed. Heck, i would store that data as a cookie rather than in the session so that it's easily accessible.

Comment: I can't really use a cookie in this case as the system will not function if the browser is blocking cookies.  I would just appear to be broken.  But again, thanks for helping.  I appreciate it.

Comment: You realize, the session relies on cookies, right? I guess unelss you're using session tokens in the url.

Comment: Good point Kevin.  Like I said, I am fairly new to this so I didn't consider that.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, an example - adapted from an existing project. Names have been changed to protect the innocent :)

First, the HttpHandler. This responds to a specific jQuery AJAX request that asks for the value of a session variable. As it's returning JSON, create a simple object to return the results (the return type can of course be as complex as you need): -

(Again apologies for this being C# not VB.NET; I've tried to make it as straightforward as I can)

```
[Serializable]
public class ResponseItem
{
    public string SessionVariable { get; set; }

    public ResponseItem(string sessionVariable)
    {
        this.SessionVariable = sessionVariable;
    }
}
```

For simplicity's sake, add the HttpHandler to your web project. You should download the latest version of Newtonsoft.Json and add a reference to it first. This handler simply take whatever is passed in the Request "sessionVariableName" parameter, try to retrieve a Session variable of that name and return its value as a String: -

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http : / /  namespace not important for your test")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class Handler : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{
    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string json = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request["sessionVariableName"]))
            {
                string sessionVariableName = context.Request["sessionVariableName"];

                if (context.Session[sessionVariableName] != null)
                {
                    var response = new ResponseItem(context.Session[sessionVariableName].ToString());
                    json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // you might want to create an "Error" type to return as JSON here
        }

        context.Response.Write(json);
    }
}
```

You'll need to register your handler in web.config; I'll assume you're using IIS7 or above: -

```
  <system.webServer>
.
.
.
    <handlers>
      <!-- Custom HTTP handlers -->
      <add name="Handler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Handler.ashx" type="YourProject.YourNamespace.Handler, YourProject" />
```

Finally, the front end. A simple test form: -

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSessionVariableName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtResponse" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" /> 
    <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="javascript::CallHandler()" />
</div>
```

Method to call the handler: -

```
function CallHandler()
{
    $.getJSON("Handler.ashx", 
     {
             "sessionVariableName": $("#txtSessionVariableName").val()
     },
     handleResult);
}
```

Callback method to handle the result: -

```
function handleResult(result)
{
    var sessionItem = eval(result);
    $("#txtResponse").text(sessionItem.SessionVariable);
}
```

To test this, type the name of a session variable you know exists in your app; the handler should return it, and the callback function will write the contents to txtResponse.

Sorry if that's a bit of a long example; let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Thanks! I will dig in and try to learn something from this.  Thanks for taking the time to help.  I will let you know how this goes!

Comment: Thanks again.  I picked up a lot of good pointers here for future reference.  So in the end,  I ended up with a bit of a quick hack as I ran out of time, threw a hail Mary and it worked!  I ended up setting an asp:hidden field at the end of the OnUnload function that was wiping my data.  I just ran out of time.  Again, I learned several nice things here so thanks for taking your time to help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery AJAX and an HttpHandler. Make sure to make your HttpHandler implement IRequiresSessionState in order to access the current Session.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate(v=vs.110).aspx

And I'd use Newtonsoft.Json, not the standard Microsoft lib, to convert to and from JSON.

Comment: Thank you sh1rts.  I am reading the Microsoft documentation now.  Just curious why you are suggesting the addition of the HttpHandler.  I may find the answer as I read, but I would like to hear your take on it.

Comment: You're welcome :) I'd go for that approach because it's a lot leaner than an UpdatePanel, which posts the ViewState to and from a page with each partial postback - not as efficient as posting to a handler. It's not much more development effort for a better result, IMO.

Comment: That would be very nice of you if you have one.  So you are saying replace the UpdatePanel?  I am not sure if I can in this case, I am embedding a reportviewer inside the UpdatePanel to handle refreshes on the report after that button is clicked.  But I will try anything you provide.  Thanks again.

Comment: No you don't need to replace the UpdatePanel if it's already there and doing a job. You can use an alternate Ajax approach on the same page. I'll get a sample together and post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks again for helping.  It has been a long hard project and it is down to the last few bugs :)  So you don't waste your time, here is my complete code and the more general question.  I asked the question you answered because someone pointed me in this direction.  But here is the overall issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653178/asphidden-field-variable-from-code-behind-loses-value-on-return-from-server-ins

Comment: Just one problem - the HttpHandler I have is C#; can you translate that ? It's not much code..

Comment: I was asking a more narrow question regarding the session variable to see if the approach Vikrants made would work.  I can't get his approach to work, so I narrowed in on the session variable retrieval approach and formed the question you answered on this page.

Comment: Yes.  Absolutely.  I code in both.  It is just the javascript stuff I struggle with :)